# Python logging: Set level in `main.py` and inherit to child loggers

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a Python project that looks like this:

```
my_project
  |- my_dir
  | |- part_1.py
  | |- part_2.py
  | |- ...
  |- main.py
```

Every file (`main.py` and `part_1.py`, `part_2.py`, ...) should be able to write to the same log file, with the following two requirements:

The file name should appear in the log message: a line in the log file should look like

`ERROR - my_dir.part_1 - Something went wrong in part_1.py`

The log level for *all* loggers should be set programatically from `main.py`:

```
# main.py
from my_dir import part_1, part_2, ...
...
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')
result_1 = part_1.my_function()  # Logger in part_1.py should be set to DEBUG level

logger.setLevel('WARNING')
result_2 = part_2.my_other_function()  # Logger in part_2.py should be set to WARNING level
```

I accomplish the first requirement by beginning each file in `my_dir` with

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Setting the same level for all loggers works if I use a config file and do `logging.config.fileConfig('config.ini')`. But changes to the log level made in `main.py` are not propagated to the other loggers. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Could make part1 and part2 inherit from a common parent class that deals with logging files and setting the flags you need. For example, a class, `Loggable`, that holds methods like `setLevel()` and `log()`

Comment: You mean by passing `Loggable` as function argument to all functions in all files?

Comment: No, I mean make a part1/part2 class that is inherited from the `Loggable` class such that all methods available in Loggable is available to all of your subclasses. If you are unfamiliar with polymorphism in Python, you can read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: Thanks, that would work! But is there a solution that achieves a better separation of concerns? The main concern of the module is to implement business logic, and it seems counterintuitive to put logging at the very center of the implementation.